# Grafana and influx with proxmox get total rx and tx in and out pet month

Tags: grafana, influxdb, proxmox

So I'm trying to get the total TX and RX in and out in grafana from proxmox.

I currently have the traffic of the RX and TX, but not the totals. I'd like to have a fixed bar with the usage of every month, over a year.

[image: RX and TX]

The screen above is what I currently got for the rx and tx, but I'd like to see a bar chart per month or per day with the total of used RX and TX (in and out)

This is the query I have for the screen posted above:

[image: query]

Raw:

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative(mean("receive"), 10s) AS "Rx" FROM "nics" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$server$/ AND "instance" = 'enp3s0') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

and

```
SELECT non_negative_derivative(mean("transmit"), 10s) FROM "nics" WHERE ("host" =~ /^$server$/ AND "instance" = 'enp3s0') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

I tried the following for total in per month/day, but this doesn't work at all.

[image: What I tried]

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: `GROUP BY time(1d)`

Comment: I always get "No data points".